# Javascript Max Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data, and my json data max result is 250

I want to add 250 result to **.list** div 
and
I want to add 100 result to **.list-2** div

I'm waiting for your help.

```
function m(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
      if (a.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
        var link = a.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
      }
    }
  }

  var title = a.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
  var result = '<a href="'+link+'">'+title+'</a>';

  $(".list").append(result); // 250 result
  $(".list-2").append(result); // 100 result
}
```

Comment: include a paste of the data

Comment: You’ve got a missing `'`. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is fill the results array inside your loop, then create the needed html from them, and finally append them with the appropriate length :

```
function m(a) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
      if (a.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
        results.push({
          title: a.feed.entry[i].title.$t, // or maybe a.feed.entry[i].link[j].title.$t ?
          link: a.feed.entry[i].link[j].href
        });
      }
    }
  }

  results = results.map(function (result) {
    return '<a href="' + result.link + '">' + result.title + '</a>';
  });

  $(".list").append(results.slice(0, 250).join('')); // 250 results
  $(".list-2").append(results.slice(0, 100).join('')); // 100 results
}
```

Note that I have joined to array of results with no seperator, if you need some html seperator you simply need to pass it as an argument to the **.join()** calls.

Comment: Friend, i can not "if else statement" in results.push({

Comment: No easier formula?

Comment: What do you mean if else in results.push ? Is my solution not doing what you expected ?

Comment: solution is ok. but "if else" codes is not working in "results.push({ });"

Comment: You can't put an if else statement inside a function call, why do you want to do that ?